# Gremlin query edge history

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I am using Gremlin, TinkerPop, AWS Neptune.

I have the following use case:
I need to query edge history, e.g. I have a connection between two points and I want to check the changes over time. If I am doing edge update I am losing the history, if I am adding edges for each update(like append-only) I have a lot of edges per vertex, if I am adding property per update e.g. {time_stamp: updated_value} I have complex queries because I have a lot of properties per edge.

What is the right way to handle this?
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure this question needed closing as it makes sense to someone working in this field. It is actually quite a commonly asked question. A commonly adopted solution, as edges cannot have meta properties, is to give each edge a time stamp and to periodically prune the old ones. How often are you needing to add edges? Hourly? Daily? etc.

Comment: Just following up again - if you could say a bit more about the use case, especially the frequency at which you need to add edges, that would help in terms of giving you some suggestions.